# Download file with react failed even though the request was successful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I am trying to download a file from my server in the client using react and node. This is the code I am using to implement the download btn in the front-end:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class DownloadBtn extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      fileDownloadUrl: ""
    }
  }
  
  dofileDownload(){
    console.log(this.state.fileDownloadUrl);
  }

  handleFile (response){
    console.log(response);
    const blob = new Blob([response]);                   // Step 3
    const fileDownloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // Step 4
    this.setState ({fileDownloadUrl: response.url},//fileDownloadUrl}, // Step 5
      () => {
        this.dofileDownload.click();                   // Step 6
        URL.revokeObjectURL(fileDownloadUrl);          // Step 7
        this.setState({fileDownloadUrl: ""})
    })
  }

  handleClick (){
    fetch(this.props.fileName, {
      method: 'GET',
      'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
    })
    .then((response) => this.handleFile(response));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Button onClick={() => this.handleClick()} variant="outline-primary">Download</Button>
      <a 
         download={this.props.fileName}
         href={this.state.fileDownloadUrl}
         ref={e=>this.dofileDownload = e}
         >download</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DownloadBtn;
```

The server is working. When I inspect

```
GET http://localhost:3000/gcode/lucas/1623843541661.gcode
```

request I can see the file in the body of the response. But when I `console.log(response)` I get:

```js
Response {type: "basic", 
url: "http://localhost:3000/gcode/lucas/1623843541661.gcode",
redirected: false,
status: 200,
OK: true,
  body: ReadableStream,
  bodyUsed: false,
 …}
```

The content of the downloaded file:

```
[object Response]
```

Can anybody tell what is wrong? Why isn't it downloading the right file even though the request is successful? Is there any other easier way to download a file from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `blob` method provided by the response object ([Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)).

Replace the `handleFile` method with:

```js
handleFile(response) {
    console.log(response);
    response.blob().then((blob) => {
        const fileDownloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        this.setState({ fileDownloadUrl: response.url }, () => {
            this.dofileDownload.click();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(fileDownloadUrl);
            this.setState({ fileDownloadUrl: "" })
        });
    });
}
```

The `Blob` constructor accepts an array containing the file content ([Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob)). Any value which is not the expected type will be converted to string. The default string representation of a response object is `[object Response]`.